# Can I move gardener to plot containing 4 bamboo?

Tags: takenoko

Is it possible to go on purpose with the gardener on the tile which has already grown 4 bamboos on it? The reason for this is that I want grow bamboos on the adjacent titles of the same color which are irrigated and have 3 or less bamboos on them.

It is nowhere specifically written that this can/can't be done, so I am interested in your opinions.

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: As far as I understand, you can do it, because it´s not forbiden.

Answer (score 3):

It is not forbidden.

From these [rules](https://s3.amazonaws.com/geekdo-files.com/bgg297888?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22TAKENOKO_rulebook_EN.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJYFNCT7FKCE4O6TA%2F20220711%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220711T200450Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=91ec1ace65315bc6c701368b10d345b8939462e7d2041c940044c7cd3c81157f)

> Important: Sections never grow in non-irrigated plots, even if the
> gardener finishes their move on the plot or on an adjacent plot.

Also

> The gardener and the panda can cross or end their movement on the pond.

The rules are explicit that the gardener can move to spaces where bamboo will not grow but it does not affect growth on adjacent irrigated plots.

If these are allowed then it would follow that moving to a plot containing 4 bamboo shoots is also allowed even if bamboo can not grow there.